# Spark : How to combine multiple window-aggregations performed on the same sliding window

Tags: scala, performance, apache-spark

I am processing a time-series dataset and I need to calculate `stddev, mean` etc over a sliding window of (-100 , +100).
I observed that the windowing is applied for each of these calculations even though the sliding window is same for all these.
Is there a way to combine all these calculations, so that there will be only one single window and all the required calculated fields are derived upon that window

```
  val w = Window.partitionBy("raw_data_field_id").orderBy("date_time_epoch").rowsBetween(-100,100)
  val rawdatax = rawdata
    .withColumn("valueSqrtStdDev", stddev_pop(col("valueSqrt")).over(w))
    .withColumn("valueSqrtMean", mean(col("valueSqrt")).over(w))
    ....
```

[image]

Comment: Do you see any skipped operations?

Comment: nothing skipped

Comment: i am going to try

Comment: On a small subset I got a different DAG Ui

Comment: thats interesting

Comment: tried similar with 1M rows, different plan. Spark 2.4+

Comment: Im on Spark 2.3.4, with 70k records, hows your plan look like? where is the difference? can you edit the question/ or add an answer with your findings if possible?

Comment: import spark.implicits._
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._
import org.apache.spark.sql.expressions.Window

val rdd = sc.parallelize(0 until 1000000).map(i => (i%1000, i,i+1,i+2))
val df0 = rdd.toDF()

val w = Window.partitionBy("_1").orderBy("_2").rowsBetween(100,200)
val df1 = df0.withColumn("valueSqrtStdDev", stddev_pop(col("_3")).over(w))
             .withColumn("valueSqrtMean", mean(col("_3")).over(w))
             .withColumn("valueSqrtStdDev", stddev_pop(col("_4")).over(w))
             .withColumn("valueSqrtMean", mean(col("_4")).over(w))
//df1.explain()

Comment: Try this and tell me what you get.

Comment: ok, ill try, btw.. you are using a window rowsBetween(100,200), I am using rowsBetween( -100, +100). Not sure if that can cause a change in the plan

Comment: i will try, but...

Comment: No difference to be detected. May be you need to show complete coding.

Comment: have u resolved this?

Comment: @thebluephantom, not yet.. got busy with something else, so procrastinated on this

Answer (score 2):

If you really want to use multiple operations over one window you could use UDF/UDAF.

An example of using UDF:

```
val multipleAgg = udf{ (ls: Seq[Double]) =>
  //perform multiple aggregations
}

val w = Window.partitionBy("raw_data_field_id").orderBy("date_time_epoch").rowsBetween(-100,100)
val rawdatax = rawdata.withColumn("aggregated", multipleAgg(collect_list(col("valueSqrt")).over(w)))
```

But on the other hand, for performance reasons, I would keep using the built-in DataFrame API if possible. You might be interested in reading this [article](https://medium.com/teads-engineering/spark-performance-tuning-from-the-trenches-7cbde521cf60) re: advantages of DataFrame/Dataset API over UDF/UDAF.

Normally in your case the data gets re-partitioned only once, after the first window function. So any concern of data movement and performance is not relevant here.

Comment: Thanks.. also the article is nice and helpful